# PDO: Different results with SQLite BETWEEN

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

I have a SQLite table with dates in unix timestamp format, which I query via PHP `PDO`. I'd like to mark the rows according to a date range, in my case whether the date falls in the winter semester or the summer semester of the year.

The start and end dates are arbitrary, but in my case I picked
`start` as March 1st (0301) and `end` as September 14th (0914), so I could easily check with `BETWEEN`.

When I run this query in PHP, like so, it returns an incorrect result (`"WS"` for all rows):

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT CASE WHEN 
    (CAST(strftime("%m%d", class_date, "unixepoch") AS DECIMAL) 
    BETWEEN :start AND :end) 
    THEN "SS" 
    ELSE "WS" END 
    AS semester FROM dates');

$statement->execute(array(
    ':start' => 301,
    ':end' => 915
));
```

But when I embed the start and end dates as numbers, instead of binding them, it works correctly (some rows `"WS"`, some `"SS"`):

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT CASE WHEN 
    (CAST(strftime("%m%d", class_date, "unixepoch") AS DECIMAL) 
    BETWEEN 301 AND 915) 
    THEN "SS"
    ELSE "WS" END 
    AS semester FROM dates');
$statement->execute();
```

What is happening here and how can I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation of [PDOStatement::execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) says that it accepts

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as **PDO::PARAM_STR**.

This means that even if you put in `301` it will be treated as `"301"`. 
Instead you should use [PDOStatement::bindValue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). Like this:

```
$statement->bindValue(':start', 301, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':end', 915, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I suspected it had something to do with type, but I would never have thought of bindValue as a possible solution.